# representing Json Object data on a DataTable is not working for me

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I am working on a java web application (Spring Frame work). Once a certain URL is hit, a Json object is created. I have access to this data and I was able to console.log it. But I need to display this Json object which is an array of more than 1000 of record in a table format. The thing that I am not sure is how to do it. I have used this tutorial(https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html), to do some thing but I was not successful. I am very new at this concept and my question might be really dump. But I was wondering maybe I can get some help from here.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
>    
<h:head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src ="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resource/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></link>

</h:head>

<h:body>
    <button id="processData">ProcessData</button>



    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <h2>List of processed data</h2>
        </div>
    </div>



    <table id="dataTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID1</th>
                <th>ID2</th>
                <th>Number Of Matching Terms</th>
                <th>Matching Terms </th>
                <th>Original Terms in Data Source One</th>
                <th>Original Terms in Data Source Two</th>
                <th>Acceptance Action</th>
                <th>Decline Action</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>ID1</th>
                <th>ID2</th>
                <th>Number Of Matching Terms</th>
                <th>Matching Terms </th>
                <th>Original Terms in Data Source One</th>
                <th>Original Terms in Data Source Two</th>
                <th>Acceptance Action</th>
                <th>Decline Action</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

    <script src="js/mainJs.js"></script>

</h:body>
```

here is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#processData").click(function (){
        $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/gtlc/PVJson', function(data){
            console.log(data);

        });

        var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable( {
            "ajax": data,
            "columnDefs": [ {
                "targets": -1,
                "data": null,
                "defaultContent": "<button>Click!</button>"
            } ]
        });

    })  

});

</html>
```

when I look at my console I can see the following:

[image]

here is the error I get 
[image]

Here is a small sample of my json object

```
"records": [{
    "id1": 1200314690100003429,
    "id2": 1045,
    "matchingTerms": ["adaptor"],
    "orginalTermsTable1": ["AC ADAPTOR FOR JDE", "www.greenlightcorp.net", "AC ADAPTOR FOR JDE", ""],
    "orginalTermsTable2": ["Greenlight Technologies, Inc.", "GRC Adaptor for People Soft", "Customized software for SAP, therefore version not specified"]
}, {
    "id1": 1200314690100003429,
    "id2": 1046,
    "matchingTerms": ["adaptor"],
    "orginalTermsTable1": ["AC ADAPTOR FOR JDE", "www.greenlightcorp.net", "AC ADAPTOR FOR JDE", ""],
    "orginalTermsTable2": ["Greenlight Technologies, Inc.", "GRC Adaptor for Oracle", "Customized software for SAP, therefore version not specified"]
}]
```

I was wondering if some one could give me some hints on how I can get a hold to the json object and represent it on the dataTable

Comment: You might need to move `var table = ...` and the rest of that block to immediately after your console.log, i.e., remove the `});` after console.log. It think datatables can't find `data` because it's in a different block of code. (?) The error is line 16, but which line is that?

Comment: @Wass, thank you for your hint. It does not throw me the previous error, But it does not show the data in the table either. It prompts me with this warning : DataTables warning: table id=dataTable - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Comment: @user1836957, please consider accepting answers to this and your other past questions if they helped you out to show your appreciation to those responded and mark questions as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the DataTable is being initialized a microsecond after ajax request.

When the Ajax request is sent, it might take 1, 2, 3 or 10 seconds to come back with the data... so `data` is undefined until the Ajax response comes back.

Move your DataTable initialization in the callback function at it should work.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8hgrsg6s/14/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = {
    "records": [{
      "id1": 1200314690100003429,
      "id2": 1045,
      "matchingTerms": ["adaptor"],
      "orginalTermsTable1": ["AC ADAPTOR FOR JDE", "www.greenlightcorp.net", "AC ADAPTOR FOR JDE", ""],
      "orginalTermsTable2": ["Greenlight Technologies, Inc.", "GRC Adaptor for People Soft", "Customized software for SAP, therefore version not specified"]
    }, {
      "id1": 1200314690100003429,
      "id2": 1046,
      "matchingTerms": ["adaptor"],
      "orginalTermsTable1": ["AC ADAPTOR FOR JDE", "www.greenlightcorp.net", "AC ADAPTOR FOR JDE", ""],
      "orginalTermsTable2": ["Greenlight Technologies, Inc.", "GRC Adaptor for Oracle", "Customized software for SAP, therefore version not specified"]
    }]
  };
  var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
    "data": data.records,
    "columns": [{
        "data": "id1"
      },
      {
        "data": "id2"
      },
      {
        "data": "matchingTerms",
        "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return data.length;
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "matchingTerms"
      },
      {
        "data": "orginalTermsTable1"
      },
      {
        "data": "orginalTermsTable2"
      },
      {
        "data": "",
        "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return "<button>Click</button>";
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "",
        "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return "<button>Click</button>";
        }
      }
    ]

  });

});
```

Better solution :

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9vjko5bv/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url" : "http://localhost:8080/gtlc/PVJson",
      "dataSrc" : "records"
    },
    "columns": [{
        "data": "id1"
      },
      {
        "data": "id2"
      },
      {
        "data": "matchingTerms",
        "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return data.length;
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "matchingTerms"
      },
      {
        "data": "orginalTermsTable1"
      },
      {
        "data": "orginalTermsTable2"
      },
      {
        "data": "",
        "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return "<button>Click</button>";
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "",
        "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return "<button>Click</button>";
        }
      }
    ]

  });


});
```

Comment: @vyc.ca, thank you. It does not throw me the previous error, But does not show the data in the table either. It prompts me with this warning : DataTables warning: table id=dataTable - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Comment: typo: "data is not undefined" >> data is undefined.

Comment: @wazz Thanks. fixed.

Comment: @user1836957 DataTables are picky when you're learning it. It looks like your JSON records are nested inside a wrapper named "records". DataTables looks for a JSON that starts with "data". You need to define the dataSrc that corresponds to the data you want to show (More information here : https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) If you can paste a small snippet of your JSON, I can create a working example for you.

Comment: @vyx.ca thank you very much. I have edited my question to show small sample of my json object

Comment: @user1836957 Here is the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8hgrsg6s/13/ I didn't load the CSS so it looks ugly but it works. The best solution would be to use DataTable's internal Ajax function instead of wrapping it inside a getJSON function... like this : https://jsfiddle.net/9vjko5bv/1/

Comment: @vyx.ca thank you very much. It worked as it was expected. I had questions from your code though. I would like to understand your code and learn from it.        "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return data.length;
        } - what this part does ? what is the job that render does in here? also the code that you put in the button section, and why data:"" for buttons?     {
        "data": "",
        "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return "<button>Click</button>";
        }
      } and what render means in the code related to the buttons?

Comment: @user1836957 here's an update fiddle with comments: https://jsfiddle.net/8hgrsg6s/21/

Comment: @vyx.ca, thank you very much for the comments, very clear and informative. one thing I did in order to understand the value of each part I commented out       {
        "data": "matchingTerms",
        "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return data.length;
        }
      } section of the code. It works the same. So what it the value of this piece of code ? Does it define how many row the table has to have ? the other question I had was, let say I want to add a functionality to each button to save the result some where, where do I add those functions in the code?

Comment: @user1836957 in your JSON, "matchingTerms" is an array. The column name you had in your table is named "Number Of Matching Terms". I just thought you wanted to show a number depending on the size of the array. To get the number of elements in an array, you need to use array.length... As to attach event listeners on your newly created buttons, I suggest you read jQuery's method "on". Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8hgrsg6s/28/

Comment: @vyx.ca: Thank you very much. Your explanation makes sense. t totally missed the part for calculating the number of matching terms. You are right !!!! You are so generous and giving. I don't know how to thank you man. you helped and taught me a lot with this question. Wish I had some one like you around :) Many thanks

Comment: @user1836957 my pleasure!